# trying to round a number to nearest whole 100th number, Math.round only rounds after decimal

Tags: javascript, adobe, rounding

In adobe javascript calculation field, I'm trying to round a whole number to nearest 100th, example:

round $2946.16 to $2900

and $2955.42 to $3000

```
var DP2 = Number(this.getField("DownPaymentBeforeTTL").valueAsString);
var SST = Number(this.getField("SubmissionSalesTax").valueAsString);

event.value = (Math.round(DP2+SST))
```

`Math.round` only rounds decimals in adobe javascript calculation text field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could divide the number by 100, round it to get an integer, and then multiply back by 100:

```js
var total = DP2 + SST;
event.value = Math.round(total / 100) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

A little cheat
Math.round((DP2+SST)/100)*100